# Un bootstrapping a juju/orchestra environment

Tags: juju, orchestra

I think my juju environment in my orchestra server is broken, and I want to do the bootstrap process again.
Basically, I'd like to run:

```
juju bootstrap
```

and not get:

```
2012-02-09 19:51:48,503 INFO juju environment previously bootstrapped.
```

How can I reset things, and re-bootstrap?

I also noticed that juju installed the zookeeper on node1 of my environment. Is there a way to get juju to install zookeeper on the orchestra server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

juju destroy-environment will shutdown all the machines in orchestra that juju was running (tagged in orchestra with the configured 'acquired-mgmt-class'). For juju to think its already bootstrapped, there is a running orchestra machine that has been recorded as the bootstrap server.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue and I resolved it by performing **sudo juju bootstrap** instead of `juju bootstrap`.